# Why do I get "Error: Could not open database"?

Tags: react-native, sqlite, react-native-sqlite-storage

I'm using the Android emulator so I put [users.db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg07z.png) in 'android/app/src/main/assets/users.db'. I already ran `npx react-native link` to make the link. I'm using a React Native version above 6.0 with auto-link.

I'm getting "[Error: Could not open database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p2l7.png)":

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View, Text, Alert} from 'react-native'
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage'

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    SQLite.openDatabase({name:'users', createFromLocation:1}, this.connected, this.failed)
  }

  connected= () =>{
    Alert.alert('Connected with success !')
  }

  failed= (e) =>{
    Alert.alert('Something went wrong !', `${e}`)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>Testing SQLite</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When changing the attribute `createFromLocation` to number 2 the system creates its own database which comes empty, so you need to create the tables. Unfortunately I didn't manage to use my old database.

Answer (score 4):

I removed this from the react-native.config.js and it worked

```
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": {
  platforms: {
    android: {
      sourceDir:
        "../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/platforms/android-native",
      packageImportPath: "import io.liteglue.SQLitePluginPackage;",
      packageInstance: "new SQLitePluginPackage()"
    }
  }
}
```

Ref : [Github](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/issues/462#issuecomment-941580281)

Comment: after hours of debugging. This is the solution for me. Previously unable to insert data when using android emulator or ios simulator. Only works on real device. But after removing script like above. Everything works.

Comment: this solution saved my job!

Comment: but do you know I am searching for a job?. Haha this is the world's reality

Comment: feel free to follow me on LinkedIn(https://www.linkedin.com/in/vmmoorthy/) and twitter(https://twitter.com/vmmoorthi25/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your db into `assets/www` folder to make it works.

Answer (score 2):

The pre-populated database was read only after I completely uninstalled the app from the device and re-installed it from scratch with `npx react-native run-android`.

It was not enough to simply reload the app while it was already on the device.

Answer (score 0):

The full file path for the database should be "\android\app\src\main\assets\www".